# Unable to distribute Xamarin iOS iPad archive because of "Missing required icon file"

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, ios8.1

I have a Xamarin unified iOS project using MVVMCross 3.5 beta which I am trying to distribute using the Application Loader.  I keep getting the following errors:

[image]

Here is what my assets look like in my Asset Catalog:

[image]

As you can see above I have all of the required images for an iPad only application.  Has anyone seen this before?

I'm using Xamarin Studio 5.7 with Xamarin iOS 8.6.0.41 on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I actually had everything set up correctly.  This is an error in the latest version of Xamarin iOS 8.6.0.  You can find the fix here:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=25569